# Three js - Referencing individual meshes in imported blender scene

Tags: three.js, blender

I am new to three.js and I have a basic blender scene with 2 different meshes which I have also named.  I have managed to import the meshes into three but I would like to know how to reference and manipulate each mesh?  is it possible if the 2 meshes are in the same file or should I load mesh1.js, mesh2.js etc?

This is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">



  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
  <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>

  <script>

    // Set up the scene, camera, and renderer as global variables.
    var scene, camera, renderer;

    init();
    animate();

    // Sets up the scene.
    function init() {

      // Create the scene and set the scene size.
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
          HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

      // Create a renderer and add it to the DOM.
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
      renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      // Create a camera, zoom it out from the model a bit, and add it to the scene.
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 20000);
      camera.position.set(0,6,0);
      scene.add(camera);

      // Create an event listener that resizes the renderer with the browser window.
      window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
            HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      });

      // Set the background color of the scene.
      renderer.setClearColorHex(0x333F47, 1);

      // Create a light, set its position, and add it to the scene.
      var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
      light.position.set(-100,-200,100);
      scene.add(light);

      var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
      light2.position.set(-100,200,100);
      scene.add(light2);

      // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
      var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
      loader.load( "tree-land.js", function( geometry, materials ){
        var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add(mesh);

      });

      // Add OrbitControls so that we can pan around with the mouse.
      controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    }


    // Renders the scene and updates the render as needed.
    function animate() {


      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      // Render the scene.
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      controls.update();

    }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mesh variable you have declared is an Object3D, which can be manipulated using all the methods and properties as seen in the documentation: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D

It looks like the call to JSONLoader.load returns a single geometry and material via the callback, so would not seem to support loading multiple files in a single call or multiple geometries in a single file. You might want to take a look at some of the other loaders for that purpose. I have successfully used the ColladaLoader (not in the documentation). Blender exports to Collada as well. The code is in examples/js/loaders of the repository.